# On reparametrisation of curves (sorry for trivial question but I'm confused)

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm confused about speed and reparametrisations of curves. To illustrate my confusion please let me elaborate using the simplest example I could think of:

Let $\gamma : [0, 2 \pi ) \to \mathbb R^2$ be the unit circle

$$\gamma (t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$$

If we multiply by a factor of $2$ this become the circle of radius two:

$$\beta : [0, 2 \pi ) \to \mathbb R^2, \hspace{0.5cm} \beta (t) = 2 \gamma (t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t)$$

Taking the derivative we see that this has speed $2$ at every point $\beta(t)$. So by scaling we also changed the speed. So far, I'm good.

But now consider

$$ \alpha : [0,2\pi ) \to \mathbb R^2, \hspace{ 0.5cm } \alpha(t) = 2\gamma \left({t \over 2}\right)$$

This is a unit speed parametrisation of the circle of radius two. My problem with this is that ${t\over 2}$ really means that we go around at half the speed of $\gamma$. But since the circle is actually twice a big it seems to me we should be going around at double the speed of $\gamma$. To confused matters more the curve $\alpha$ is actually unit speed...

> Please could someone help me resolve my confusion?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the curve $\alpha:[0,2\pi)$ only maps the positive semicircle of radius 2: this is half the length of the circle of radius 1. so its length is $2 \pi$. Your curve goes at speed $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parametrize all the circle, you will need to allow, in the parametrization $\alpha(t)=2\gamma(\frac{t}{2})$ , t to range from $0$ to $4 \pi$

Comment: Which is perfect, since the total arclength is $4\pi$ :)